# Including source for Alchemy js breaks Highcharts js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, include

Alchemy JS is a graph visualization platform, when I include it in my code it breaks the already present Highcharts. This problem is easily demonstrated here [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2t87Lyz/1/). If you remove `<script src="http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.min.js"></script>` then the chart renders perfectly (as it should, I snagged it from the [highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic)).

The only error in the console is `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function` so I am at a bit of a loss over it. I tried beautifying and linting the alchemy src and while the lint is not clean, the errors seem to be inconsequential regex problems.

Comment: Try to change order of loading files. I mean run alchemy before highcharts.js, http://jsfiddle.net/v2t87Lyz/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading Alchemy before highcharts appears to fix the problem. `<div class="alchemy" id="alchemy"></div>` can be anywhere. [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2t87Lyz/6/)